# Failed to find attribute 'app' in '__main__'

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Im trying to deploy a web app using flask to heroku using gunicorn. I've been trying for roughly 2 days but with no luck. I currently have this error:

> Failed to find attribute 'app' in '__main__'.

I know the error is saying that it couldn't find `app` in `__main__.py` but I don't know why it couldn't find it as `app` is in `__main__.py`, as you can see below.

'Procfile'

```
web: gunicorn __main__:app
```

'__main__.py' (first 9 lines and last 2 lines)

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, session, g
import random
import requests
import mysql.connector

from oauth import Oauth
from oauth2 import Oauth2

app = Flask(__name__)

# 200 removed lines of flask code that powers the backend goes here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is what my directly looks like if it helps:

```
web
-static
-templates
-__main__.py
-oauth.py
-oauth2.py
-Procfile
-requirements.txt
```

Here is the full error logs from heroku

```
2021-01-27T12:55:26.211031+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-27 12:55:26 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-01-27T12:55:26.213834+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'app' in '__main__'.
2021-01-27T12:55:26.214015+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-27 12:55:26 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-01-27T12:55:26.223266+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-27 12:55:26 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-01-27T12:55:26.226404+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'app' in '__main__'.
2021-01-27T12:55:26.226731+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-27 12:55:26 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-01-27T12:55:26.359501+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-27 12:55:26 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-01-27T12:55:26.359767+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-01-27 12:55:26 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
2021-01-27T12:55:26.447672+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 4
2021-01-27T12:55:26.511220+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

It runs fine **without** gunicorn on **localhost** on **my laptop** but not hosted on heroku with gunicorn.

Comment: I'd avoid the filename `__main__.py` as `__main__` is a builtin python term. Try naming that file `app.py` then use the procfile: `web: gunicorn app:app`

Comment: oh, that makes sense - no wonder it couldn't find the app attribute, it was looking in the wrong place. Thanks for your advice. :)

Comment: @v25 I think you should make your comment an answer was stuck there for a while
I was looking for a quick way to run a flask app by just doing `python .` and ended up stuck with the __main__ error

Comment: @zonecc Answered.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid the filename `__main__.py`, as `__main__` is a builtin python term.

Try naming that file `app.py` then use the Procfile: `web: gunicorn app:app`